# Good practices when adding downloaded c++ source code to my project

Tags: c++, gcc, include

I am trying to use gnuplot++, but this is really a more general question about downloaded source code. I have downloaded the gnuplot++ source code and it consists of multiple .h and .cc files. I would like to use it in othercopy projects in the future so I am reluctant to add all the files into my project directory.

From what I understand gcc will look in /usr/local/include for header files, so I have put the code there for now. But what is the best way to compile and link the code?

1. Should I use the makefile to include the directory of the source code?
2. Should I keep it somewhere easy to find like /usr/local/include?
3. How do I know the best way to compile the code in gnuplot++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general practice, yes, keep the source for gnuplot++ (or any other similar 3rd-party project) separate from your own application source code.  This makes it much easier to manage updates to the 3rd party projects, etc.

Yes, I would use the makefile for your application to also include the path to the headers for gnuplot++ and I would not copy those files directly into /usr/local/include.  Instead, I would consider a couple options: do nothing and point your include path in your makefile to the gnuplot++ directory, or put symbolic links in /usr/local/include to point to the gnuplot++ files.

As for the best way to compile gnuplot++, I would have to look at gnuplot++ myself and see what it has to say, perhaps in a README file or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you have confirmed what I was starting to gather from my research. I guess at the end of the day, I am going to have to do some work myself to get library into my project through my makefile. Unfortunately there is no such README file and I can't find one online, there is a sample makefile though which I may be able to use for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, if the project itself doesn't come with install instructions, I usually add it somewhere "public", e.g. `/usr/local/project/{lib,include,src,...}` where "project" in this case would be gnuplot++.

In this case, there doesn't appear to be any support for building this into a library, which makes it a little more awkward, as you need the sources included in your project itself. I'd still keep those sources separate, but you may prefer to just put them into a separate directory within the project [or spend an hour or three making a library of it].

Answer (score 0):

In general, when using third-party libraries, you build and install those libraries according to the installation description that comes with the downloaded source.

If there is no installation guideline, it is typically a set of steps like

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Then it is the responsibility of the library to ensure the relevant headers and library files are easily locatable for use in your project.

gnuplot++ is an exception here, because it does not seem to come with its own build structure.
The best advice in cases such as this is to put the source from gnuplot++ in a directory within your project (possibly parallel to your own sources) and include the files in your own build setup.